# Unity: Can't reference namespace (or even method in a different script)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I'm building an AR project in Unity with Vuforia and using a demo version of AVPro Video to stream via HLS. All I want to do is call the Pause() method from a script in the AVPro namespace (using RenderHeads.Media.AVProVideo) from within a Vuforia script when tracking is lost, and Play() when tracking is found again. However, I can't get my editor to recognize the other class within the RenderHeads.Media.AVProVideo namespace or even the  namespace itself.  I think it has to do with assembly references or folder levels (via https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ScriptCompileOrderFolders.html ) but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to solve it properly? 
[Here is a picture of the assembly references in my project, showing that VuforiaScripts and VuforiaEditorScripts exist outside of the level of scripts contained in the editor assembly? ...if that's a thing?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqeMV.png)

The errors I get are:

> Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs(14,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Renderheads' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have tried deleting and reimporting the AVPro Video demo, updating Visual Studio, starting completely over and rebuilding my project, and nothing.

Here's the code for the vuforia script I modified (irrelevant parts not posted, just my additions):

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
using RenderHeads.Media.AVProVideo;


public class DefaultTrackableEventHandler : MonoBehaviour, ITrackableEventHandler

{   protected MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    public GameObject ResponsiveMediaPlayer; 


    public virtual void Start()
    { mediaPlayer = ResponsiveMediaPlayer.GetComponent<MediaPlayer>(); }


    public virtual void OnTrackingFound()
    { mediaPlayer.Play(); } 


    public virtual void OnTrackingLost()
    { mediaPlayer.Pause();   } }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT**: Solved! This had to do with the order of script compilation! I had to gather all the AVPro scripts into a single folder, then I made an assembly definition so the scripts would be compiled at the same time as the Vuforia Scripts, since they were compiling before anything else. To make an assembly reference, right click on the folder of the scripts you want it to reference, and create > Assembly Definition. Make sure Auto-Referenced and Use GUIDs is checked. The assembly definition will automatically reference all the scripts in the same folder that it is in. Next, to be able to reference it from within the Vuforia scripts, I found the VuforiaScripts.asmdef file (the VuforiaScripts assembly definition) and in the inspector under "Assembly Definition References" I added the one I just made. I hope that helps!

Comment: What is the folder path of the `DefaultTrackableEventHandler` script and the folder path of the `Renderheads.Media.AVProVideo` library/scripts, relative to your 'Assets' folder ?

Comment: @Tenretni the path for the main script (DefaultTrackableEventHandler) is ProjectName/Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/ and the path of the Renderheads.Media.AVProVideo library/scripts is at ProjectName/Assets/AVProVideo/Scripts/Components/ .

Comment: Does AVProVideo use assembly definitions ?

Comment: @Tenretni I've been trying to learn more about assemblies and assembly references to make sure I understood what you were asking, thanks for your patience! Within AVPro Video I don't see any files that end in .asmdef, .dll or .exe if that's what you mean?